# Fixed Navbar when scroll in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

i have a problem with android and the scrollview.
I want see the textinput when the soft keyboard opens.

So i use this component => https://github.com/sarovin/react-native-scrollview-smart

But the problem is that the navbar is not fixed at the top but it disappears...

[image: Gif of error]

The navbar is a component of react-native-router-flux => https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: have u tried to you navigationBar? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html

Answer (score 5):

Use react native's keyboar avoiding view 
[KeyboardAvoidingView](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/KeyboardAvoidingView.js) and [Example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/js/KeyboardAvoidingViewExample.js)
Like

```
import {ScrollView, Text, TextInput, View, KeyboardAvoidingView} from "react-native";
```

and  in render function nest the `View` and `TextInput`

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position'>
                <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
                  <TextInput
                    value={pin}
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    keyboardType='default'
                    returnKeyType='next'
                    onChangeText={this.handleChangePin}
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                    placeholder={I18n.t('pin')}/>
                </View>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </ScrollView>
```

It will take care of that

Comment: Are there any special rules for using KeyboardAvoidingView...like does it need to be the first child of a ScrollView or anything like that? I've tried using it with v0.36 of react-native on a relatively simple ScrollView page and it doesn't work with padding or height.